# React native: adding a third party - Native module RNvectorIconsModule tried to override vectorIconsModule

Tags: java, react-native

I'm new to react-native. I'm trying to manually add a third-party pacakage called react-native-vector-icons: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

I tried to install the npm and then follow the manual steps. The error I'm getting is:

[image]

Upon checking my MainApplication.java it doesn't seem that the module is created twice right?

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  packages.add(new VectorIconsPackage()); // THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED
  return packages;
}
```

Why am I getting this error?
Thanks

Comment: Try `cd android && gradlew clean `

Comment: Thank you very much it didn't work, I had to downgrade my react-native version to 0.59.0

Comment: Sounds Good @sir-haver

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have version **0.60** or higher at least because they come up with **Autolinking of packages** in this release.

Remove the line you have added in MainApplication.java,:

```
packages.add(new VectorIconsPackage()); // THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED -- *remove this line*
```

Also, remove **import** related to this i.e.,

```
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have issue on react-native `60+`.
They use auto-linking for native modules. So you don't need call `react-native link` anymore.

Call `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons` and try again.

For react-native `< 0.60` you should check duplicates in MainApplication.java.